# Should account-merging be mentioned in the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, faq-proposed

It occurred to me today after I encountered two "different" users with the same name and gravatar (though one of them recently changed names...and genders, apparently...but I digress) that it might behoove the site to make it known (or at least more knowable) that account merging is an option. I, for one, was fortunate to have someone happen along early in my time here, after I'd registered my first account, who pointed out that I could have my unregistered accounts merged into that one. I don't think users should have to rely on luck for that, though.

Does it seem worth mentioning to folks (who at least take the time to read through the faq) that account merging is possible (arguably even encouraged)?

Comment: If neither of these accounts are registered, I don't see much point in merging. OTOH, mods are no longer able to merge accounts; interested users can go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge), however.

Comment: @Ｊ.M.: Oh, my! When (and why) did they lose that ability?

Comment: About a few months ago, I believe. There were some concerns over privacy; see e.g. [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132025).

Comment: Willie Wong also [made an announcement on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8403/8348) in February.

Answer (score 2):

It already is there in the new help center at https://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/merging-accounts

Comment: Huh. A help center. Who knew?